# How can my Telegram bot forward a message?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm creating a Telegram bot and I need to put the customer in direct service with the attendant, in this case, I need the bot to do this redirection when the customer requests it.

I pass the function like this:

```
bot.forward_message(chat_id=chat_id_cliente, from_chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message['message']['message_id'])
```

The log:

```
ERROR:root:Error transferring service: 'TelegramBot' object has no attribute 'forward_message'

bot.forward_message(chat_id=chat_id_cliente, from_chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message['message']['message_id'])
```

expected that the attendant receives a message from the customer

Comment: Is `bot` a [`telegram.Bot`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.6/telegram.bot.html)? Please provide a [mre]